# Datastore gorm failing to run app after updating to grails 3.2.2

Tags: grails, grails-orm

after updating to grails 3.2.2. I get the following error after grails run-app:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/datastore/gorm/plugin/support/ConfigSupport
    at   grails.plugin.hibernate.HibernateGrailsPlugin$_doWithSpring_closure1.doCall(HibernateGrailsPlugin.groovy:54)
```

When I remove all datastore stuff from build.gradle the app starts, but thats not what i want.

Thanks for any help

Here are my dependencies:

```
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.11.Final"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:4.3.10.Final"

compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-core:5.0.12.RELEASE'
compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-simple:5.0.12.RELEASE'

compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-support:5.0.12.RELEASE'
compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:5.0.12.RELEASE'
compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4:5.0.12.RELEASE'
compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core:5.0.12.RELEASE'
```

Comment: What plugins and other related dependencies are you using?

Comment: It seems you are missing the `grails-datastore-gorm-support` dependency in your project. This is a transitive dependency of the `hibernate5` plugin https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/blob/master/grails-plugin/build.gradle#L24

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing an old version of GORM (5.0.12) in your dependencies whilst Grails 3.2 needs GORM 6. That is your problem. Remove these dependencies (all dependencies starting with `org.grails:grails-datastore-`) to proceed.

Comment: Thanks!! That was it